# What is request.getSession(false) for?

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails

Im currently into Grails in Action book on the part wherein the author is writting a custom tag named loginToggle under a TagLib class

I don't quite get what is `request.getSession(false)` is for

```
def loginToggle = {
    out << "<div style='margin: 15px 0 40px;'>"
    if (request.getSession(false) && session.user){
        out << "<span style='float:left; margin-left: 15px'>"
        out << "Welcome ${session.user}."
        out << "</span><span style='float:right;margin-right:15px'>"
        out << "<a href='${createLink(controller:'brewUser', action:'logout')}'>"
        out << "Logout </a></span>"
    } 
    else{
        out << "<span style='float:right;margin-right:10px'>"
        out << "<a href='${createLink(controller:'brewUser', action:'login')}'>"
        out << "Login </a></span>"
    }
    out << "</div><br/>"
}
```

Great book BTW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above code means, if there is a session (but don't create one) and contains a user.

Check the docs:

> [`HttpSession getSession(boolean create)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)
>
> Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.
>
> **If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null.**
>
> To make sure the session is properly maintained, you must call this method before the response is committed. If the container is using cookies to maintain session integrity and is asked to create a new session when the response is committed, an IllegalStateException is thrown.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> `create` - true to create a new session for this request if necessary; false to return null if there's no current session
>
> #### Returns:
>
> the HttpSession associated with this request or null if create is false and the request has no valid session
>
> #### See Also:
>
> `getSession()`

Comment: can I not simply leave it like if(session.user)?

Comment: this would most likely create a new session.  it depends on your site, but usually it is a good idea to keep away from state as long as you can.